# Unability to authenticate user created by php in Active directory

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap, windows-server

I'm working on Windows server 2008 R2 where I have installed active directory. I have two types of users. The one i've created directly on my active directory server, and the one i'm creating with a relative php code, as my goal is to create a website with which I can interract with the ldap server. The problem is that only the users created on active directory can authenticate while they're member of the same group and get the same privileges.

The authentication code :

```
// Search for the user in the active directory
  $filter = "(sAMAccountName=$pseudo)";
  $result = ldap_search($ldap_con, $searchdn, $filter);

  if ($result) {
      $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_con, $result);
      echo $result;

      if ($entries["count"] == 1) {
          // user authentication
          $user_dn = $entries[0]["dn"];
          
          $ldap_bind_user = ldap_bind($ldap_con, $user_dn, $mdp);
```

I have the `Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials` error.

I have tried modificating the "obligation to change the password at first login" manually and with php code which did not work. I've also tried changing user's privileges but i did not succeed solving the issue.

Comment: Are you connecting via LDAP or LDAPS? I believe the default configuration disallows cleartext auth (i.e. no simple binds on unencrypted connections).

Comment: @user1686 Yes i must be connected via LDAP as my authentication to the active directory server is just made from a ldap_bind function. Do I have to authenticate via LDAPS to be able to allow cleartext authentication ?